# url to requestflowtest is not working

Tags: magento-1.7, layout, controllers

I have gone through this tutorial on youtube

[Quick start to magento customization - part 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KtBaozxkFgI)

As I don't have knowledge on php, I understood only the configuration layout part.

The video says that if we type `localhost/magento/requestflowtest`, we will see a page saying **Helloworld**. but I am getting error "*404 not found*".

What I have done by going through the tutorial is as follows:

- In app/code/local  --> created a folder name "Practice" (*case sensitive*)
- In app/code/local/Practice --> created a new folder name "ControllerTest"
- In app/code/local/Practice/ControllerTest/ --> created a new folder name "etc"
- In app/code/local/Practice/ControllerTest/etc  --> created a xml file "config.xml" . The content in it is as follows:

### config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0."?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Practice_ControllerTest>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Practice_ControllerTest>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <test_controller>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Practice_ControllerTest</module>
                    <frontName>requestflowtest</frontName>
                </args>
            </test_controller>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

- Then in app/etc/modules --> Created a new xml file with name "Practice_ControllerTest.xml" and added the following content:

### Practice_ControllerTest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Practice_ControllerTest>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Practice_ControllerTest>
    </modules>
</config>
```

- Then in app/code/local/Practice/ControllerTest --> added a new folder "controllers"
- In app/code/local/Practice/ControllerTest/controllers --> added a new php file with name "IndexController.php" and added the following content to it:

### IndexController.php

```
<?php
class Practice_ControllerTest_IndexController
extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    /*
     * General report action 
     */
    public function indexAction(){
        echo "<h1>Hello World!!</h1>";
    }
}
```

What could I have been doing wrong here?

Comment: Try renaming `indexController.php` to `IndexController.php` and make sure your Magento caches are disabled or flushed.

Comment: @Tim Sorry, it was typo, I updated my post. and I cleared the cache. Still same 404 issue.

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere else because before this I tried one of the alanstorm's tutorial which displayed the same error.

Comment: Just now I reinstalled magento and did the same what I explained here (didnot follow the video again) on the fresh copy. but still it is showing 404 error. I think I am missing something in this.. may be I am passing the wrong url. I even tried `http://localhost/magento/index.php/requestflowtest`, still same error.

Comment: Do you have your module listed in admin `Configuration \ Advanced \ Advanced`?

Comment: @Tim yes at very bottom with name `Practice_ControllerTest`.

Comment: anything in Magento logs (make sure they are enabled)?

Comment: @Tim I enabled the log. [here is the log text](http://ideone.com/Gdh7z1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would appear you have an extra . in your config.xml first line

```
<?xml version="1.0."?>
```

Should be

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

I only noticed this when I copied your code across to one of my magento instances that has $_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'] enabled. This showed me that there was an error with the xml.

Comment: Sharp eyes :D. thanks.. such a silly mistake. I was writing it manually..